# Confused about version numbers between windows phone 7.5 and windows phone sdk 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7

I just bought an htc pro 7 which was with windows phone 7. I upgraded it with zune today and it says update available is **7.1**.

So I don't understand did it upgrade my phone to Mango or not ? Why doesn't it say 7.5 then ? So is zune refering to version of the sdk instead ?

Comment: This is not a programming question. It would better suited to one of Stack Exchange's other Q&A sites.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone#Updates) :

> - 7.0.7008 - Improvement for future update
> - 7.0.7390 - Codename "NoDo" with Copy and Paste, fast application startup, and deeper Facebook Integration
> - 7.0.7392 - Revoking of fraudulent certificates
> - 7.0.7403 - Pre-Mango
> - **7.10.7720 - Windows Phone 7.5 Mango available now**
> - 7.10.7740 - Fixed email issue in Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 and voicemail notification issue.

And from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_7.5) :

> Windows Phone **7.5** (codenamed 'Mango') is a major software update for Windows Phone, the mobile operating system by Microsoft. **Although the OS internally identifies itself as version 7.1**

So yes, your phone has the Mango update.